# Is there really a power tunic in Final Fantasy 2 (aka Final Fantasy IV) for the SNES?

Tags: snes, final-fantasy-4

Is there really a "power tunic" in Final Fantasy 2 for the SNES? The instruction manual lists this as an item, but I can't find it. Which itself isn't strange, but I can't find any mention of it online either.

The only evidence of this I can find online is [this](http://www.angelfire.com/games4/finalfantasy2tsc/armors.html) page, which is basically only contains information from the instruction manual.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - the "Power" tunic/robe/vest/sash (depending on the translation) is an item that is dropped by Behemoths.  (King Behemoths drop it as well, but these only appear in the GBA version)

I think in the SNES version of the game it was just "(robe icon) Power"

The [Final Fantasy Wikia](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Power_Sash) gives its stats as:

> It grants the wearer +15 to Strength and has 15 Defense. In the DS version it also gives 10 to Evasion.

I found a FAQ for the SNES version that lists the drop rate from Behemoths as 11/64 (see the comments below) - so you're likely going to have to farm some Behemoths if you're interested in getting one.

Comment: Wikia's entry does not make any mention of whether this was in the North American SNES version of Final Fantasy IV: it was definitely in later releases, but that's not what the question asks.

Comment: @MarkTrapp that's a good question about localization.  I've got the Playstation 1 version, personally.  I'll see if I can find a SNES reference to confirm it was present there too.

Comment: According to this [dropped item FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/snes/522596-final-fantasy-ii/faqs/11842) (Copyright 2001, Paul D. Shoener III (Paulygon), attributed as requested in the document) which appears to be based on the US SNES release of the game (See the translation of "Cocktric") the Behemoth has a 11/64 chance of dropping a Power Robe.